# Let ${ w_1 ,\ldots, w_m }$ be a linearly independent set in $R^n$ and let $ v_1 , \ldots, v_m$ denote the

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\displaystyle\{ w_1 ,\ldots , w_m \}$ be a linearly independent set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $v_1 ,\ldots , v_m$ denote the
orthonormal basis obtained by performing the Gram-Schmidt procedure on $w_1 ,\ldots , w_m$ and then normalizing. Prove that the matrix T defined by

$$\displaystyle(T )_{ ij} = \Big<w_j , v_i\Big>,\quad 
1\leq i, j\leq m$$ is invertible.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Any attempts towards the solution, so far?

Comment: Yeah ! I was trying using Gram-Schmidt but i got struck.

Answer (score 3):

If $v = \alpha_1 w_1 + \cdots +\alpha_n w_n$, then
$$
         v = \sum_{k=1}^{n}\alpha_k \sum_{j=1}^{n}\langle w_k,v_j\rangle v_j
           = \sum_{j=1}^{n}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\langle v_j,w_k\rangle \alpha_k\right)v_j.
$$
That means $[ \langle v_j,w_k\rangle ]_{j,k}$ is the transition matrix from the basis $\{ w_1,\cdots,w_k \}$ to the basis $\{ v_1,\cdots,v_k \}$, which makes the matrix invertible.

Answer (score 3):

If $A$ is the matrix having $v_1,v_2,\dots,v_m$ as columns and $Q$ is the matrix having $w_1,w_2,\dots,w_n$ as columns, we know from the Gram-Schmidt algorithm that $A=QR$ for an invertible matrix $R$.

Then your matrix is exactly $Q^TA=Q^TQR=R$.

How is the matrix $R$ built? The Gram-Schmidt algorithm builds vectors $u_1,\dots,u_m$ such that
$$
v_j=\alpha_{1,j}u_1+\dots+\alpha_{j-1,j}u_{j-1}+u_j
$$
where
$$
\alpha_{ij}=\frac{\langle u_i,v_j\rangle}{\langle u_i,u_i\rangle}
$$
Setting also $\alpha_{j,j}=1$ and $\alpha{i,j}=0$ for $i>j$, we see that
$$
A=Q_0R_0
$$
where $Q_0$ has the vectors $u_1,u_2,\dots,u_m$ as columns and $R_0=[\alpha_{i,j}]$ has the found coefficients as entries.

The normalization produces $Q$ by dividing each column of $Q_0$ by its norm and $R$ by multiplying each row of $R_0$ by the norm of the corresponding column in $Q_0$, so that $A=Q_0R_0=QR$.

The matrix $R_0$ is invertible because it is triangular with $1$ on the diagonal, so $R$ is invertible as well.

Since by construction $Q^TQ$ is the identity, we have the stated equality.

Answer (score 3):

No calculations required here:

$\mathcal B=(v_i)$ is a basis of a subspace $V$, and  $\mathcal B'=(w_i)$ is an *orthonormal basis* of $V$.

As $\,v_i=\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^n \langle v_i,w_j\rangle w_j$, the columns of $T$ are the coordinates of the vectors of $\mathcal B$ in basis $\mathcal B'$, hence it is the change of basis from $\mathcal B'$ to  $\mathcal B$, which is invertible, like all change of basis matrices.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Show that $T$ is lower-triangular and that it diagonal entries are non-zero.

That is, show that if $j > i$, then $T_{ij} = 0$, and that $T_{ii} \neq 0$ for all $i$.

Comment: How can I show this, I am not able to show. can you please give some clue how I can find the solution. Thank you

Comment: Does it make a little bit more sense now?

Comment: still not getting

Comment: Can you prove that, because of the way the G-S process works, $w_j$ will be perpendicular to $v_i$ whenever $j > i$?

Comment: By G-S process $\displaystyle u_i=w_i-\frac{<w_i,u_1>}{||u_1||^2}u_1-.......\frac{<w_i,u_{i-1}>}{||u_{i-1}||^2}u_{i-1}$ and $v_i=\frac{u_i}{|u_i||}$

Comment: But on the other hand, we have
$$
u_1 = \langle u_1, w_1\rangle w_1\\
u_2 = \langle u_2, w_1 \rangle w_1 + \langle u_2,w_2 \rangle w_2
$$
and so on